# What are the best resources to learn Magento API?

Tags: magento-1.7, api

Are there any complete tutorials/books/blogs available for learn Magento API from the beginning? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it's pretty hard to find good Magento API resources.

For learning about the SOAP API, I used/can recommend:

- magentocommerce.com: [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/%E2%80%8E) (there were lots of mistakes on the old version of this website, hope it's better now)
- Alan Storm:  [The Magento API](http://alanstorm.com/magento_api_tutorial)
- Inchoo: [Magento API v2](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/)
- agoraDesign: [Creating or updating products](http://www.agoradesign.at/blog/creating-or-updating-products-magento-soap-v2-api-very-challenging-adventure)
- [Magento SOAP call](http://blog.plan2.net/2011/03/04/magento-eigenen-soap-api-call-implementieren/) (german resource)
- stackoverflow/stackexchange questions ;-)

Actually this is a list of the visited websites from my PC ;)

And of course I learned the most with debugging and testing.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through each section of the below is a good starting point:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

And then the below after:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api

Answer (score 2):

I read the most for learning about the API from here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/introduction

Answer (score 1):

Another very good article with regards to Magento API has been written by Inchoo:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/

They list the differences between the APIs which exist in Magento starting at the basics like "What is a WSDL", "How to access Magento by creating a role and user", "Differences between API v1 and v2" and also include screenshots of where to find the resources.

This article helped me a lot when I programmed my first API methods.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link and +1. I already followed the wiki articles. Hope this will provide more knowledge in API